# Zxing using custom layout

Tags: android, zxing

I'm using `ZXing` Library this way:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:2.2'
    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-minimal:1.2.1@aar'
}
```

And in `Activity`:

```
IntentIntegrator.initiateScan(this);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

And it looks like this:
[image]

But I don't know how to add a back button on this camera preview. How can I create a custom layout with camera on background and back button on front?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem a while back so finally I borrowed and customised the code from Andreas Schildbach [bitcoin wallet](https://github.com/schildbach/bitcoin-wallet). This will create a small camera view in the screen while you have other views.

I put the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/n4cr/97b120d72db16340a50c).

Its a QRCode scanner and there are buttons and EditText around it. Also it has a an overlay rectangle for better finding the middle of the screen.

Comment: it's not that simple. can you provide ScannerView?

Comment: can you also provide colors? by the way using butter knife is so good)

Comment: Well the colors are not that special but I posted them.

Comment: thanks a lot man, i would like this answer but i have low priority

Comment: i noticed that it's only for qr codes. Can i implement for all types of codes? is there a universal decoder?

Comment: AFIK zxing supports that. you probably have to use another type of reader instead of `QRCodeReader`

Comment: @Nasir Can you please provide same example for Barcode?

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari the thread is too old. I'm not active in this area anymore